# Why my points have fallen down without any reason?

Tags: discussion

On askubuntu.com I have 470 points:
[image]
But when I click on meta user, I have 510 points:
[image]

**This morning I found 501 point** on my profile on askubuntu.com. Then suddenly, without any reason, I noticed after few minutes that my points have fallen down to 470. Why this ?

Comment: You can see the reputation changes on your profile, that might explain.

Comment: @Jobin There is no notification. All what I see is an other +5 (I am 475 points now) and a new badge, nothing new apart from that. Strange .

Comment: did you down vote any answers?

Comment: @AvinashRaj No, I never downvoted an answer since I subscribed to this website.

Comment: I also lost points in the past, when a question was migrated to another site. E.g. to Superuser or Unix & Linux SE site.

Comment: From the screenshots, there is something funny going on with your badges as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *is* strange.

- It's not a reversal. Sometimes if somebody bulk-votes for you, some of those votes will be automatically reversed and they show as negative points.
- It's not something you've done. I can't see any recent negative vote spends and the bounty you places was ages ago.

All I can really say is it doesn't affect your actual reputation. Your main account is your actual account (the meta one is just an occasionally-synchronised copy) so its score is the correct one. You don't appear to have lost any rep. It just seems to be a calculation error on the meta side of things.

Comment: now, my points on this meta user website has fallen down also.

Comment: it could be the first case you mentioned

Comment: I don't think it can be a reversal. I would be able to see it.

Comment: Does reversal apply when someone closes an account? Or is it some other mechanism then?

Comment: @muru There are automatic and manual ways of reversing votes between people too, but all methods can be seen by moderators.